# ssh error while logging in using private key "loaded pubkey invalid format" and "error in libcrypto"?

Tags: ssh, key-authentication

***UPDATED***

When I am trying to generate a public key it still gives me an error
"error in libcrypto"

Load key "breakthis": error in libcrypto

***Private key is given below***

I am trying to solve a Hack the box machine

I was able to get a private key 
then I converted that private key into a hash for JOHNTHERIPPER and cracked it successfully

But now when I try to login in through ssh I am getting the following error
I have searched a lot but not able to resolve these error

---

```
ssh -i id_rsa joanna@10.10.10.171

load pubkey "id_rsa": invalid format 

Load key "id_rsa": error in libcrypto

joanna@10.10.10.171's password:
```

---

Comment: I am still getting an error "error in libcrypto"

Comment: Update your question with how you are attempting to connect after generating the public key from the private key.

Comment: As mentioned by Alex, a using a public key in `~.ssh/.config` seems to cause cause the `error in libcrypto` for me as long as that key is not loaded by a running SSH agent. It happened for me when my keeagent crashed. However, restarting the agent seems to allow such setup as mentioned in [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/669593/keepass-keeagent-ssh-keys-how-to-integrate-with-a-bash-terminal)

Comment: @NasirRiley "You are supposed to use the public key to connect via ssh, not the private key." - that is not true.

Comment: @Drew Yes, it is. When one uses `ssh-copy-id`, for example. the public key is sent, not the private key. The file `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` for virtually every Linux distrubution as well as FreeBSD has a line for `PubKeyAuthentication`. Notice that it's not `PrivKeyAuthentication`.  The private key is not what one wants to send over. One has to generate a private key but that's not what's actually used to connect. That should be evident from the message that one receives if it fails. That's why it's called the private key.

Comment: @NasirRiley your explanation is absolutely irrelevant to the OP as in this context both private and public keys are used in ssh communication. Private is on Client side, public is on Server side. But in the comment above the use of public key was suggested on a client side which is not correct. Besides, the public key is not being sent on every session initiation - it's just being used to encrypt and transfer the ephemeral (session) key for symmetrical encryption. But again it's irrelevant to the OP.

Comment: @Drew Make up your mind. First you state that my statement about the using public key to connect isn't true (which isn't true itself) and now it has become that it's not relevant to the OP. I haven't seen any comments from the OP indicating that so what is or isn't relevant isn't known unless you can read minds. In fact, the OP hasn't responded in nearly three  years so who cares? At this point, you are arguing just to argue.

Comment: @NasirRiley Your statement is wrong. I am simply correcting the wrong information. End of the conversation.

Comment: @Drew If that makes you feel better and is the end of you arguing for the sake of it, then I welcome it. Hopefully, you've found something more important than something on the internet that hasn't had any activity in nearly three yeas.

Comment: Just to clear up confusion for anyone stumbling across this comment chain, the private key is indeed what you need to connect each time. As proof, try `ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` (or equivalent) and see what happens. You need `ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa`. You can use the `file` command on the key files to see what kind of key they are. Indeed, the server needs your public key in its known_hosts for you to connect, but that is a one-time operation and is not a routine part of establishing SSH connections to a server.

Answer (score 28):

In my case I had copied the keyfile using the clipboard, which had created a similar file but without terminating newline. That was enough to trip up libcrypto. Opening the file in vim and `:wq` closing it, was enough to add the newline, and it fixed my issue.

Comment: haha this is such a stupid issue, surely it is a bug? why would a newline at the end of the file be a hard requirement

Comment: Mine was a different problem... but replacing every "\n" with actually "enter" in nano editor has solved my problem. :-)

Comment: I had a similar issue caused by copying to the clipboard - the issue was my pasted file then had Windows CRLF line endings. The solution was to convert to Unix LF line endings (which can be done in Sublime Text)

Comment: No success with vim, but I used `dos2unix .ssh/id_keyfound` and it worked

Comment: This reminded me to wrap my ssh key in base64 format in gitlab-ci variable. Hope it helps someone.

Comment: I switched to a new computer, pasting my ssh keys into new files manually. This fixed the issue for me. Cheers.

Comment: The only thing that helped me was to copy the key as file instead of using the clipboard

Answer (score 19):

> ERROR: load pubkey "id_rsa": invalid format

It happens when public key is used in ~/.ssh/config instead of using private key.

Answer (score 8):

I fixed the `Load key "id_rsa": error in libcrypto` error by adding an `LF`
control character (new line) at the end of the last line `-----END OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY-----` of the `.pem` file.

Before (doesn't work):

[image]

After (works):

[image]

Note the additional `LF` control character in the last non-empty line. One can add an `LF` control character by simply hitting the <kbd>ENTER</kbd> key.

Commands used to SSH into my remote computer:

```
chmod 400 key.pem
ssh -i "key.pem" ubuntu@myserver.com
```

Note: the error message can be either:

- `Load key "id_rsa": error in libcrypto` (I saw it on my Ubuntu computer).
- `Load key "key.pem": invalid format` (I saw it on my Windows computer) .

---

To show End of Line control characters in Notepad++:

[image]

Comment: This is the answer if you are coming here from GitLab CI. As a File variable it will truncate the trailing newline. Adding a simple extra newline in the variable solves the issue.

Answer (score 4):

for future readers.
I was using a ssh key file inside **Gitlab CI** YAML file and I kept getting `error in libcrypto` message.
I did 2 things that **FIXED** the problem:

1. Just changing the variable type from `FILE` variable to `ENV_VAR`
2. Using `ssh-keygen -t ed25519` when generating the key. Looks like gitlab does not support the default `rsa` keys.

Then everything works fine.

Also use this as the base `before_script`:

```
  before_script:
    - 'command -v ssh-agent >/dev/null || ( apt-get update -y && apt-get install openssh-client wget gnupg -y )'
    - wget -qO- https://get.docker.com/gpg | apt-key add -
    - eval $(ssh-agent -s)
    - echo "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY" | tr -d '\r' | ssh-add -
    - mkdir -p ~/.ssh
    - touch ~/.ssh/config
    - touch ~/.ssh/known_hosts
    - chmod -R 400 ~/.ssh
    - ssh-keyscan <ip> >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
    - '[[ -f /.dockerinit ]] && echo -e "Host *\n\tStrictHostKeyChecking no\n\n" > ~/.ssh/config'
```

Comment: this helped me so very much - thanks !!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

I got this error, when I was using 2 github accounts with 2 ssh keys, but get rid of this error when i changed my config file like below,

```
myDir$ ssh -T git@github.com
Load key "/home/taxi/.ssh/mhmd_personal.pub": error in libcrypto
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
```

From this

```java
Host *
  AddKeysToAgent yes
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/mhmd_personal.pub
  # IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_ed25519
```

to

```java
Host *
  AddKeysToAgent yes
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/mhmd_personal
  # IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_ed25519
```

removed the **.pub** extension from config file.

Comment: This does not fix the error.

Comment: some other git error may show similar error message, I am here to help

Comment: Thank you @Md.SultanulArefin
This was a life saver!

Answer (score 0):

I just have fixed this problem. This problem was caused because of the format of the text.

Replace following the ssh-key format, Its looks like this:

```
-----BEGIN OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY-----
ENCODED KEY DATA HERE
-----END OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY-----
```

Comment: For the next time; there's no need to do this manually. Command `ssh-copy-id -i /pathto/privatekey user@remotehost` will copy the corresponding public key in the correct format to the target :-)

Answer (score 0):

what fixed it for me was the [answer to this question](https://superuser.com/a/59522/328089)

I opened the key in `puttygen` then exported a new ppk using the conversion --> Export OpenSSH Key

Answer (score 0):

So in my case the private key file was simply missing the read permissions for the owner. After adding the read permission (`chmod u+r id_ecdsa`), everything worked fine.